# Adding additional fields dynamically to a rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-5, associations

Seeing some tutorials I tried to build some nested forms with option to add fields dynamically when a add button is clicked.
I am completely new here and finding it difficult to solve the problem as my code does not work , neither it gives any error !
Here is the form

```
<%= form_for [@project, @feature], class: "form-group inline", remote: true  do |builder| %>

    <%= builder.fields_for :tasks, remote: true do |form| %>
      <%= render "task_fields", f: form %>
    <% end %>

    <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Field", builder, :tasks %>

    <%= builder.submit class: "btn btn-primary m-2" %>

<% end %>
```

And the Application helper method `link_to_add_fields` is->

```
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
  end
```

And the js code is ->

```
$(document).on 'click', 'form .add_fields', (event) ->
  time = new Date().getTime()
  regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
  $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
  event.preventDefault()
```

The problem is there shows no error but does nnothing(only performs the href="#" action).
How can I achieve the functionality such that I can add fields dynamically to nested form

Comment: Is it necessary to build your own solution? There are many nice libraries which does nested fields out of the box. For example [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon)

Comment: yes I cannot use a gem, thats where the problem is @cnnr

Comment: @Achy97 open Developer tools in browser and go to the 'Add Field' field button DOM node and then click on the button in page and see if you can see the DOM modified. If not then most likely the problem should be in the JS event handler you have written. You can debug as well using Developer tools's Debugger tool to find out what your JS is doing.

Comment: @JigneshGohel thanks I could find the error by following your instructions--Actually some dependency were not set up

Answer (score 0):

It was actually only for those dependencies in `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```